# How to enable the search box in Mozilla Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, search

Having installed Thunderbird on my new machine, the quick filter box was available, but the search box that normally lives above it has disappeared. How do I get it back?

Answer (score 3):

It is related to the 'global indexer', which enables the global search. For whatever reason, this was disabled on installation. In 78.10, the setting can be found as a checkbox under `Preferences > General > Indexing > Enable Global Search and Indexer`.